# One-liner class instance implementation

Tags: java, java-8

I need to get an instance that is implementing a certain interface

Is it possible to create a one-liner class instance implementation?

Comment: That depends on the interface (is it a functional interface?) and its required implementation.

Comment: It also depends how long the line is :-)

Comment: Yes. How awful that one line looks will depend on the complexity of the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 8, if the interface is a functional interface (exactly one abstract method, see below), you can define it via a lambda expression or in simple cases via a method reference:

Lambda:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> System.out.println("I am a runnable");
```

Method reference:

```
Predicate<Character> uppercase = Character::isUpperCase;
```

Note: functional interfaces do not need to be annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`, but it is a compile-time error to annotate an interface as `@FunctionalInterface` if it doesn't have exactly one abstract (non-[`default`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), non-[`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html#static), non-[`private`](http://aruld.info/private-interface-methods-in-java-9/)) method (so the annotation is useful in a similar manner to `@Override`).

See:

- [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) javadocs
- [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (Java tutorial)
- [Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) (Java tutorial)
- [Functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8) (Java language specification)
- [Method reference expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) (Java language specification)

---

Update answering to comments:

Yes, you can define and use a lambda with a oneliner, but that requires an explicit cast if the context is unclear:

```
// cast required
System.out.println(((Predicate<Character>) Character::isUpperCase).test('A'));

// no cast required
Arrays.asList("foo","bar").forEach(System.out::println);
Arrays.asList(1,2).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i*2));
```

Comment: just curious, can the return of that instance be returned in one line?

Comment: It’s better to only say that a functional interface has one **abstract** method, as that saves you from taking care about the different types of irrelevant methods, as there are not only `default` methods, but also `static` methods, and Java 9 will allow `private` methods, that are all irrelevant to the question whether an `interface` is a functional interface. To be more correct, it has exactly one abstract method that does not match a method declared in `java.lang.Object`, so `Comparator`, having two abstract methods, still is a functional interface.

Comment: @fireflieslive: it’s not clear what “can the return of that instance be returned in one line” is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Holger thanks, wasn't aware of private and static methods.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Something like "return XInterface x = () -> //implementation"

Comment: @fireflieslive: if the declared return type of your method is a functional interface, you can implement it as easy as `return () -> /* implementation */;`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is possible.
For example:

```
List<T> list = ...
Collections.sort(list, (t1, t2) -> compareOperation(t1,t2));
```

A `functional interface Comparator<T>` is an interface that contains only one abstract method.
[See docs.oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5)